# Update variable in the layout from component - Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have layout defined as such

```
@layout MainLayout

@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @Body

    @("_total " + _total)

    @("_perPage " + _perPage)

</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public int _total;
    public int _perPage;
}
```

Then in component receive the layout reference

`[CascadingParameter] public Layout Layout { get; set; }`

And the set it as such in

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    Layout._total = 3;
    Layout._perPage = 3;
}
```

Problem is the values in the `Layout` don't get updated. I tried with 'StateHasChanged` after the setter statements but that doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value, but there's nothing driving a `StateHasChanged` event in the Layout component.  You can:

1. Add a method to the Layout to explicitly call `StateHasChanged` which you call from your component.
2. Make your values properties and add setters that call `StateHasChanged` - can get messy!.
3. Add a specific method to set the values and call `StateHasChanged` as detailed in Surinder's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have public function to set values in your layout component like this

```
@layout MainLayout

@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @Body

    @("_total " + _total)

    @("_perPage " + _perPage)

</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public int _total;
    public int _perPage;
    
    public void SetTotal(int tot)
    {
        _total = tot;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

     public void SetPerPage(int num)
    {
        _perPage= num;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Use your Layout component anywhere like this, its important to use OnAfterRender instead of OnInitialized, as OnAfterRender is called once all html is mounted in components

```
<Layout @ref=layout></Layout>

private Layout layout;

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        layout.SetTotal(3);
        layout.SetPerPage(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Polite]  As the layout component already exists in the Renderer, there's no restriction on when to call the setters.  Change `OnAfterRender` to `OnInitialized` and everything still works.